# Mobx & React - the proper place in the code for the configure object

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have maybe a silly question: where is the best way to put a `configure` object for Mobx in the project? Or the `enableStaticRendering` option?

In the 'template' file, using for server side rendering? `main.ts` - the 'first' file? Or in App.tsx?

My project (random order):

- React/Preact
- Express
- TypeScript
- Mobx/Mobx-React

I know *what* should I use. But I don't know *how to do it properly* and where to put in the code.

I'm still new in programming so I've tried to put `configure` object or the `enableStaticRendering` option in random places in my code and watch what happens. It's not the best way, I know, but I didn't find any exact guidance in official documentation or on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a best way, but server side entry file is a good place to call it there, yes. Overall it does not matter too much, just be sure to call it before you actually render any of your `observers`.

`configure` can be placed in `App.tsx` because usually you have the same configuration for SSR and CSR

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I know what to do :)